# filter multiple values in the same condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

couldn't find the answer for this.

Say I have this ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat="books in bookList | filter:color | filter:theme"></li>
```

And multiple buttons to filter this list based on color and theme. So when I click on

```
 <a ng-click="color = {type: 1}">blue</a>
```

I filter all elements with the color blue.

But now I need to let the user filter however he wants, so let's say he wants to filter by blue AND yellow. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can pass a function to filter instead of the color object. In that function you evaluate which colors the user has selected.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom multi-value filter as below:

```js
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.selectedColors = ["blue", "red"];
    $scope.selectedThemes = ["t1", "t2"];
    $scope.items = [
      {
        color: "blue",
        theme: "t1"
      },
      {
        color: "blue",
        theme: "t2"
      },
      {
        color: "red",
        theme: "t2"
      },
      {
        color: "yellow",
        theme: "t3"
      }
    ];
   })
  .filter("multiValues", function(){
    return function(items, selectedValues, attrName) {
      var result = [];
      angular.forEach(items, function(item){
        if (selectedValues.indexOf(item[attrName]) > -1) {
          result.push(item);
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <div>Before Filtering:</div>
  <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li>{{item.color + " - " + item.theme}}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>Selected Colors: {{ selectedColors.join(", ") }}</div><br />
  <div>Selected Themes: {{ selectedThemes.join(", ") }}</div><br />
  <div>After Filtering:</div>
  <ul ng-repeat="item in items | multiValues:selectedColors:'color' | multiValues:selectedThemes:'theme'">
    <li>{{item.color + " - " + item.theme}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble filtering a color AND a theme... Let's say I have multiple blue colors but some are t1 and some t2.

How do I filter all blue, then only t1 blues or only t2 blues?